# Is it possible to compare two string in DWT

Tags: 2011, dwt

I have some requirement where i have to compare two string values in DWT code like below

```
 <!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="'title' == 'title'" -->
    .......
    <!-- TemplateEndIf -->
    <!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="'date' == 'date'" -->
     .................
    <!-- TemplateEndIf -->
```

it looks not working. Now my question is  that can  i compare string values these way.

P.S.-  it may look you guys that why i need this  but i am leaving the detail of all requirement here just for the sake of simplicity.

Thanks,

Comment: String comparisons are definitely possible, this is basic functionality - I assume one of your values is a var, not a string, so maybe what's failing is the syntax for a var in there? Try `cond="'date'==varName"` without single quotes on the var

Comment: +1 Nuno as the code in the above sample is pointless as it should always evaluate to true and thus the conditional region tags can be omitted...

Answer (score 8):

This is absolutely possible and in your case it is not working because the syntax that you have used is incorrect:

You should have written your code as

```
<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="'title'=='title'" -->
```

Instead of

```
<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="'title' == 'title'" -->
```

Mind the space before and after the equal operator.

Also, consider the suggestion given by Nuno to double check if one of the comparison entity in the if condition is a variable. The variable should not be in surrounded by `' '` whereas the text/string should have been surrounded by them.

Comment: As the value of the "cond" attribute is evaluated as a JScript expression after expanding package variable references you do NOT need to use @@..@@ here; doing so will in most circumstances create an expression that is always false as @@..@@ gets expanded and afterwards evaluated as a package variable reference...

Comment: I agree as I have overlooked it. Answer updated :)